# show last post viewed in a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins

need to show last post viewed, on frontend if user is logged. for some reason it doesnt show.
thank you for help

added a function in the included file but no results.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_last_read_courses' ) ) :

    function theme_last_read_courses() {
        if (is_user_logged_in() AND is_singular() AND get_post_type()==="courses"){
                update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'last_view_post_id',get_the_ID());

                $last_post_id = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'last_view_post_id',true);

                echo 'HTML code';

                    }

    }
endif;
```

Comment: Just to clarify : it does not show at all or it does not show if user is logged ? also, where exactly is this file ( plugin, theme ? ) and did you check that the  `'last_view_post_id'`   is really existing as meta ? take out all the conditions and see if you get results then

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' =>'courses'
   ) );

   if(($query)&& ()is_user_logged_in()){
   }
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.